# Sitepress Multilingual CMS not converting some text in other language

Tags: wordpress

I'm using sitepress multilingual cms plugin on this site http://wplt.mangoagency.com/ which is working fine but when i change the language there're are few text which is not translating in other language 
just like footer copyright text, footer widget and tagline 
is there any solution for that  ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately if the plugin did not design it that way you cannot just innately fix it without changing the code.

Inside a plugin there is a function that is used in order to translate text.  If this function wasn't used for some parts of the code, then it will not show up translated.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Inside the code you will notice sections that are text but use:

```
<?php echo _e('Page Text');?>
<?php echo __('Page Text');?>
<?php $text = _e( 'Page Text', 'domain_or_plugin_name' ); ?> 
<?php $text = __( 'Page Text', 'domain_or_plugin_name' ); ?>
```

You can edit all the code to have all the sections updated with the translation but if it was not done during creation there is no "setting" to really fix it from Wordpress.